# Using constructed string

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I wonder why this string in `werktwel` is fine but the string in `werktniet` is not when I use them in my query.

When I log them I see the same thing; `"2016-03-21*"` and the type is for both `string` when I log that as well.

```
// create data

declareUpdate();
xdmp.documentInsert(
       "/example.json",
       {"meting": "783", "bericht": "553", "plant": "01", "timestamp": "2016-03-21T22:32:30.361756"},
       xdmp.defaultPermissions(),
       xdmp.defaultCollections(),
       10)

// query
var nu = new Date();
var beteredatum = nu.getFullYear() + "-" + (Number(nu.getMonth())+1) + "-" + nu.getDate();
var werkniet = beteredatum + "*";
var werktwel = "2016-03-21*";
var a = cts.search(cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery("timestamp", werkniet, "wildcarded")).toArray();
xdmp.log(xdmp.type(werkniet));
a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I worked with the months was not ok. This way it works fine. The fix is in the slice on getMonth.

```
// query

declareUpdate();
xdmp.documentInsert(
       "/example.json",
       {"meting": "783", "bericht": "553", "plant": "01", "timestamp": "2016-03-21T22:32:30.361756"},
       xdmp.defaultPermissions(),
       xdmp.defaultCollections(),
       10)

// query
var nu = new Date();
var beteredatum = nu.getFullYear() + "-" + ("0" + (nu.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "-" + nu.getDate();
var werkniet = beteredatum + "*";
var werktwel = "2016-03-21*";
var a = cts.search(cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery("timestamp", werkniet, "wildcarded")).toArray();
xdmp.log(xdmp.type(werkniet));
a
```

Answer (score 4):

Consider using [Date.toISOString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString):

```
var now = new Date(); // Mon Mar 21, 2016 
var isoNow = now.toISOString(); // 2016-03-21T12:20:56Z
var now2 = new Date(isoNow); // Mon Mar 21, 2016
```

HTH!

Answer (score 2):

When you tried it before, I suspect the month was October, November or December. (10,11,12).  Note your fix also has a "0" prepended forcing the month to be 2 or more digits, and converted to a string.  Hence the slice(-2) will always produce the last 2 digits.

However I suggest working with the built in date and dateTime functions rather then string manipulation wherever possible especially for sub-components.
The conversion from xs.date and xs.dateTime follow ISO8601 specifications which are fixed with numeric so are more easily decomposed then composed.
E.g "2016-02-21T11:22:33.012-03:00"  (dateTime) or "2016-01-21"

Your example to get the date (beteredatum) portion of dateTime as a string can be simplified as

```
   var werkniet = fn.adjustDateToTimezone( fn.currentDate(), null ) + "*"
```

or

```
fn.substring( fn.currentDate()+"" , 0, 11)
```

or

```
  fn.formatDate(fn.currentDate(),"[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]*")
```

If you work with number to string conversions I suggest the fn.formatNumber (or xdmp.formatNumber()) which are well defined and provide 0 padding to fixed width.

e.g to get the day as a 0 padded number

```
   fn.formatNumber(fn.dayFromDate( fn.currentDate() ),"00")
```

If you stick to the builtin fn. or xdmp. date functions they interoperate well, no +/- 1, well defined string to number or date conversions and produce the correct format for all the marklogic functions that expect dates.